# DSL, extending an interface method with a lambda with receiver as argument

Tags: kotlin, generics, lambda, interface, receiver

I have the following interface with a function accepting a lambda with the same type receiver of the interface itself:

```kotlin
interface WebhookEventInterface<T> {

    operator fun invoke(block: WebhookEventInterface<T>.() -> Unit) {..}
}
```

Now I'd like to extend this interface with another one providing additional capabilities/features on top of the previous one, something like:

```kotlin
interface PushPullRequestFeatures<T> : WebhookEventInterface<T> {

    override operator fun invoke(block: PushPullRequestFeatures<T>.() -> Unit) {..}
}
```

Of course the compiler complains because there is a function signature clash in `PushPullRequestFeatures` with his super `invoke` method and `override` overrides nothing.

How can I override the `invoke` method of the super `WebhookEventInterface` in `PushPullRequestFeatures` while offering a receiver of the same type?

Comment: If you want to make it _impossible_ to call `PushPullRequestFeatures.invoke` with a `WebhookEventInterface<T>.() -> Unit`, then that contradicts what it means to "inherit from `WebhookEventInterface`". If you just want an extra overload available to implementors of `PushPullRequestFeatures`, don't use `override`.

Comment: @Sweeper I want simply to override it to offer a lambda with the new receiver. If I omit `override` in `PushPullRequestFeatures`, then there is still a declaration clash

Comment: Are you targeting the JVM? Just add a `@JvmName` annotation to give one of the overloads a different JVM name.

Comment: @Sweeper yep, I tried that but it looks like isn't possible in this case
`'@JvmName' annotation is not applicable to this declaration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, you can't (as far as I know) change the parameter types when overriding at all, so you can't change them in this particular way either.

What you can do is make the receiver type into another type parameter:

```kotlin
interface WebhookEventInterface<T, out W : WebhookEventInterface<T, W>> {
    operator fun invoke(block: W.() -> Unit) { ... }
}

interface PushPullRequestFeatures<T> : WebhookEventInterface<T, PushPullRequestFeatures<T>> {
    override operator fun invoke(block: PushPullRequestFeatures<T>.() -> Unit) { ... }
}
```

(If you don't `override`, the receiver type will be `PushPullRequestFeatures<T>` anyway because that's just what `W` is here.)